# Is there a 64 bit version of quicktime for windows 10?

Tags: quicktime

Is there a 64 bit quicktime version for windows 10? All the descriptions that I have found on-line don't state either 32 or 64bit.

Comment: Can you explain why you are interested in having a 64-bit compiled version of quicktime? Having a 64bit version would not solve any particular problem you might be having, and if you wish to use it with a browser (which are all almost exclusively still 32bit) your options woudl be limited. ITunes/Quicktime have installers available for Windows X 64bit, but that does not mean that the executables therein are compiled to be 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

No. The only download for the current version of quicktime (7.7.8) is this one: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837?viewlocale=en_GB&locale=en_GB

It's 32-bit. There are no 64-bit options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64-bit version of QuickTime, primarily because Apple has ceased development of QuickTime on Windows (except for security and minor updates, presumably). QuickTime has been 7.x for 10 years now, and 8.0 does not seem to be anywhere in the distance.

If you need a codec for QuickTime videos (and more), you would be better off installing [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016, QuickTime for Windows is no longer supported.  Apple has currently dropped support for QuickTime is OS X, as well.